# Table form dynamically refresh with php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a page which has a form table. It displays select option when an option is selected the user clicks button and it runs updatephp.php which has query for updating. I need the select to be dynamically updated and display the success/error message like "updated" or "no results" on the screen how can I achieve this. Im not very good at ajax could someone guide me please.

displaytable.php

```
<form method="POST" action="choosecake.php">
    <select id="bakeryid" name="bakeryid">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT bakeryid, datefrom FROM cakes";
            $sqlresult = $link->query($sql);
            $sqllist = array();
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlresult) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult))
                {
                echo "<option value=".$row['bakeryid'].">".$row['datefrom']."</option>";
                }
                $sqlencode = json_encode($sqllist);
                echo $sqlencode;
            } else {
                echo 'No Results were found';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $bakeryid;?>" name="bakeryid"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `displaytable.php` and generate an array of your cakes with id as key and the name as the value. Then echo the json encoded array which can be used directly in js.

Just to get a feeling, didn't test it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/displaytable.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
      var select = $('#selectId');
      select.empty();
      $.each(data, function(val, key) {
        select.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(val);
      });
    });
  }, 10000); // 10 seconds update interval
});
```

Comment: you need a third file called e.g. form.html with just the form and the JS code in it. From there we will fetch the ajax. in the displaytable.php remove the form. just build the array and echo the json_encode

Comment: sorry i don't seem to understand

Comment: You should read a book or do some tutorials. It's not possible to learn PHP here. You won't be happy and we won't be happy writing long dialogs, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If your page must refresh (no ajax), use displaytable.php to handle the form submission. Then define a variable to hold your success or error message and put this variable where you want the message to display, like

```
if(!empty($success_message)) {
    echo "<h2>$success_message</h2>";
}
```

When the form is submitted, simply assign a value to `$success_message`, and since the script handling the form submission is the same script which contains the form, the echo statement in the code above will display your message when the page reloads.